# Private Messaging System With Threading/Replies

Tags: php, mysql, insert-id

I'm currently working on creating a private messaging system, (PHP/MySQL) in which users can send message to multiple recipients at one time, and those users can then decide to reply.

Here's what I'm currently working with:

```
tbl_pm tbl:
id
date_sent
title
content
status ENUM ('unread', 'read') DEFAULT 'unread'

tblpm_info tbl:
id
message_id
sender_id
receiver_id
```

However, I need some help determining the logic on two things:

1) When a new message is created, should the "id" be auto-increment?  If the 'id' column is set to auto-increment in both tables, how would I set the "message_id" column in the 'relation table'?

For example, when a new message is created, my MySQL statement is as follows:

```
<?php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tblpm` (title, content, sender_id, date_sent) VALUES ('$subject', '$message', '$sender', NOW())" );
```

In the same statement, how would I enter the 'auto-incremented' value of tblpm into the tblpm_info "message_id" field?

2) What should my MySQL statement look like when users reply to messages?

Perhaps I am making this more complicated than I need to.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Definetely yes, id's should be auto-autoincremented unless you provide a different means of a primary key which is unique. You get the id of the insert either with `mysql_insert_id()` or `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from mysql directly, so to post some connected info you can do either

```
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 ...")
   $foreign_key=mysql_insert_id(); //this gives you the last auto-increment for YOUR connection
```

or, but only if you're absolutely sure no one else writes to the table in the mean time or have control over the transaction, after insert do:

```
$foreign_key=mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
INSERT INTO table2 message_id=$foreign_key
```

or, without pulling the FK to php, all in one transaction (I also advice to wrap the SQL as a transaction too) with something like:

```
"INSERT INTO table1...; INSERT INTO table2 (message_id,...) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),...)"
```

Depending on your language and mysql libraries, you might not be able to issue the multi-query approach, so you're better off with using the first approach.

2) This can have so many approaches, depending on if you need to reply to all the recepients too (e.g. conference), reply in a thread/forum-like manner, whether the client-side can store the last retrieved message/id (e.g. in a cookie; also affecting whether you really need the "read" field).

The "private chat" approach is the easiest one, you then are probably better off either storing the message in one table and the from-to relationships into an other (and use JOINs on them), or simply re-populate the message in one table (since storage is cheap nowadays). So, the simplistic model would be one table:

```
table: message_body,from,to
$recepients=array(1,2,3..);
foreach($recepients as $recepient)
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (...,message_body,from,to) VALUES(...,$from,$recepient)");
```

(duplicate the message etc, only the recepient changes)

or

```
message_table: id,when,message_body
to-from-table: id,msg_id,from,to

$recepients=array(1,2,3,...);
mysql_insert("INSERT INTO message_table (when,message_body) VALUES(NOW(),$body)");
$msg_id=mysql_insert_id();
foreach($recepients as $recepient)
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO to-from-table (msg_id,from,to) VALUES($msg_id,$from,$recepient)");
```

(message inserted once, store the relations and FK for all recepients)

Each client then stores the last message_id he/she received (default to 0), and assume all previous messages already read):

```
"SELECT * FROM message WHERE from=$user_id OR to=$user_id WHERE $msg_id>$last_msg_id"
```

or we just take note of the last input time from the user and query any new messages from then on:

```
"SELECT * FROM message WHERE from=$user_id OR to=$user_id WHERE when>='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$last_input_time)."' "
```

---

If you need a more conference- or forum-tread-like approach, and need to keep track of who read the message or not, you may need to keep track of all the users involved.

Assuming there won't be hundred-something people in one "multi-user conference" I'd go with one table for messages and the "comma-separated and wrapped list" trick I use a lot for storing tags.

```
id autoincrement (again, no need for a separate message id)
your usual: sent_at, title (if you need one), content
sender (int)
recepients (I'd go with varchar or shorter versions of TEXT; whereas TEXT or BLOB gives you unlimited number of users but may have impact on performance)
readers (same as above)
```

The secret for recepients/readers field is to populate them comma-separated id list and wrap it in commas again (I'll dulge into why later).

So you'd have to collect ids of recepients into an array again, e.g. $recepients=array(2,3,5) and modify your insert:

```
"INSERT INTO table (sent_at,title,content,sender,recepients) VALUES(NOW(),'$title','$content',$sender_id,',".implode(',', $recepients).",')"
```

you get table rows like
... sender | recepients
...           1 | ,2,  //single user message
 
...           1 | ,3,5,  //multi user message

to select all messages for a user with the id of $user_id=2 you go with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE sender=$user_id OR INSTR(recepients, ',$user_id,')
```

Previously we wrapped the imploded list of recepients, e.g. '5,2,3' becomes ',5,2,3,' and INSTR here tells if ',2,' is contained somewhere as a substring - since seeking for just '2',',2' or '2,' could give you false positives on e.g. '**2**34,56','1**,2**34','9,45**2,**89' accordingly - that's why we had to wrap the list in the first place.

When the user reads/receives his/her message, you append their id to the readers list like:

```
UPDATE table SET readers=CONCAT(',',TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM readers),',$user_id,') WHERE id=${initial message_id here}
```

which results in:

... sender | recepients | readers
...           1 | ,2,              | ,2,
...           1 | ,3,5,           | ,3,5,2,

Or we now can modify the initial query adding a column "is_read" to state whether the user previously read the message or not:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE INSTR(recepients, ',$user_id,'),INSTR(readers, ',$user_id,') AS is_read
```

collect the message-ids from the result and update the "recepients" fields with one go

```
"UPDATE table SET readers=CONCAT(',',TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM readers),',$user_id,') WHERE id IN (".implode(',' ,$received_msg_ids).")"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I kinda of like the "wrapped list" trick,  however, I do have one question.  Using this method, how would I also track a timestamp for when a message was actually read.  In other words, other than just tracking "is_read", I'd also like to track "when_read" by each recipient.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on auto-increment on both IDs due to the possibility of two users posting two messages at nearly the same time. If the first script inserts data into the `tbl_pm` table, then the second script manages to execute both its `tbl_pm` and `tblpm_info` inserts before the first script completes its `tblpm_info` insert, the first script's two database inserts will have different IDs.

Aside from that, your database structure doesn't seem well organized for the task at hand. Assuming your messages could be very long, and sent to a very large number of users, it would be ideal to have the message content stored once, and for each recipient have unread status, read time, etc. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `pm_data` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date_sent` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255)
  `sender_id` smallint(5) unsigned,
  `parent_message_id` smallint(5) unsigned,
  `content` text,
  PRIMARY_KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `pm_info` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pm_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `recipient_id` smallint(5) unsigned,
  `read` tinyint(1) unsigned default 0,
  `read_date` timestamp,
  PRIMARY_KEY (`id`)
);
```

Create these two tables, and notice both of them have an 'id' value set to auto-increment, but the 'info' table also has a `pm_id` field that would hold the ID number of the 'data' row that it refers to, such that you're sure each row has a primary key in the 'info' table that you can use to select from.

If you want a true relational database setup using MySQL, make sure your engine is set to InnoDB, which allows relationships to be set up between tables, so (for example) if you try to insert something into the 'info' table that refers to a `pm_id` that doesn't exist in the 'data' table, the INSERT will fail.

Once you've chosen a database structure, then your PHP code would look something like:

```
 <?php
 // Store these in variables such that if they change, you don't need to edit all your queries
 $data_table = 'data_table';
 $info_table = 'info_table';
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$data_table` (title, content, sender_id, date_sent) VALUES ('$subject', '$message', '$sender', NOW())" );
 $pmid = mysql_insert_id(); // Get the inserted ID
 foreach ($recipent_list as $recipient) {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$info_table` (pm_id, recipient_id) VALUES ('$pmid', '$recipient')" );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would definitely set auto_increment on both of the ids.

To set the message_id you would programatically insert it in there.

Your query would look like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tblpm` (title, content, sender_id, date_sent) VALUES ('$subject', '$message', '$sender', NOW())" );
```

Notice it's the same! If the id is set to auto_increment it will do all the magic for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by, "To set the message_id" you would programatically insert it in there?"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In plain PHP/Mysql calls, [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) returns the auto-incremented value from the previous INSERT operation

So, you insert the message, collect the newly generated ID, and put that value into the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Personally in your case (providing the example was not simplified and there is not more I cannot see) I would store the data from both of those table in a single table, as they appear to be directly related:

tbl_pm tbl:

message_id

date_sent

title

content

status ENUM ('unread', 'read') DEFAULT 'unread'

sender_id

receiver_id

So you end up with something like the above, there is not really any need for the join as the relationship is always going to be 1 to 1?  You have read / unread in the tbl_pm table which would surely be changed per recipient, meaning you are having to store a copy of the message for each recipient anyway.  perhaps staus is supposed to be in the tbl_pm info table.

If you do want to insert into both tables try using last_insert_id() within a query or
mysql_insert_id()  as explained above,  from within php.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something similar to what gavin recommended, but if you wanted threaded messages, you'd have to add another key, like this:

```
private_messages
- title (text)
- date (timestamp)
- content (text)
- status (enum)
- sender_id (int)
- receiver_id (int)
- parent_message_id (int)
```

Then you could have nested messages without a separate table or system.